# html image in folder not showing

Tags: html, path

structure:

```
root_project
   -templates
      -pictures
         img.png
      -home.html

   -flask_session.py
```

I am running a Flask app in flask_session.py and I want to display images in multiple flexbox containers, everything works fine if I use a link to an image, but when i use file path it just doesn't work

```
            <div class="crate crate-1">
                <img src="pictures/img.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="crate crate-2">
                <img src="/pictures/img.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="crate crate-3">
                <img src="./pictures/img.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="crate crate-4">
                <img src="img.png" /> <!-- I even tried putting the image into the same folder as my html files and also in the root file, it still didn't work -->
            </div>
```

no matter what i do i just keep getting 404's

`"GET /pictures/img.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try building the directories like this:

```
app/static/img/your_img.jpg
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The Images are in the pictures directory and your are trying to access them without root directory.
1)C:\Windows\image.png
#your complete file directory would work
2)import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
full_path = os.path.realpath(**file**)

Comment: i tried using my complete path, it still did not work though, it thinks the image is in http://localhost:5000/C:\....

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).